# Optimizing Javascript code for `<select>`

Tags: javascript

Some time ago i decided to stop using on-event attributes to seperate HTML and Javascript.

So now i have this HTML.

```
<form name="x" action="x.php" method="get">
   <label>
      <select name="language" size="1" id="languageselect">
         <option value="da" selected>Dansk (da)</option>
         <option value="en">English (en)</option>
         <option value="">Brug browserens indstillinger</option>
      </select>
   </label>
</form>
```

And this Javascript.
But i would like to know if my code can be better and it seems once in a while i get a error message in my Javascript logfile about "this.form.submit();".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';

function languageformsubmit () {
   this.form.submit();
}

function init_hjemmeside_addeventlistener () {
   var languageselect;
   if (document.getElementById('languageselect')) {
      languageselect = document.getElementById('languageselect');
      languageselect.addEventListener('change', languageformsubmit, false);
   }
}

function init_hjemmeside_attachevent () {
   var languageselect;
   if (document.getElementById('languageselect')) {
      languageselect = document.getElementById('languageselect');
      languageselect.attachEvent('onchange', languageformsubmit);
   }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener('load', init_hjemmeside_addeventlistener, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
   window.attachEvent('onload', init_hjemmeside_attachevent);
}
</script>
```

The code works fine but i would like to know if it can be better.

Answer (score 0):

you could post the exact error you're getting so we could help you.
Apart from that, it does what you want, submiting the form when you change the selected option in the select.
By the way, you could improve it by using jQuery, though maybe you don't want that.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#languageselect').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont have the error message now but i few times i saw it in the error log so i was thinking maybe i could test for something before calling this.form. And i dont want to use jquery.

Comment: Okay. The only test I can think of is whether to this or this.form are null or undefined. If you see the error, post it here.